# How to recognize the active child form and fire a common method (which exist in each child forms)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

I have a main (MDI) form and around 70 child forms which are intialized and shown 
in runtime. At a time maybe more than 1 child form can be shown. In each of the 
child forms there are button named "OK" and its event "btnOk_click(object sender, EventArgs e).
There is a button in the Parent form named "Save", if we click on it, in the 
runtime the activeMDI child forms event (btnOk_click) should get fired.

Please help me on this issue.

at present I do this issue, by using following code

```
 switch (ActiveMdiChild.GetType().Name)
            {
                case "frmSalesOrder":
                case "frmPurchaseOrder":
                case "frmSizeRatio":
                    break;
                case "frmUserGroup":
                    var _frmUserGroup = (frmUserGroup)this.ActiveMdiChild;
                    _frmUserGroup.btnOK.PerformClick();
                    _frmUserGroup = null;
                    break;
                case "frmUser":
                    var _frmUser = (frmUser)this.ActiveMdiChild;
                    _frmUser.btnOK.PerformClick();
                    _frmUser = null;
                    break;
```

Thanks
Joseph J

Comment: At present I do with a switch and code as follows;

Answer (score 8):

Interfaces could really help you here:

```
interface IChildSave {
  void SaveAction();
}
```

Then in each of your child forms, implement it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IChildSave {

  public void SaveAction() {
    saveButton.PerformClick();
  }

  private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // save routine
  }
}
```

Then your MDI Parent form wouldn't need the Switch statement any longer:

```
if (this.ActiveMdiChild is IChildSave) {
  ((IChildSave)this.ActiveMdiChild).SaveAction();
} else {
  MessageBox.Show("Child Form does not implement IChildSave.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways of doing this. Yours is one of them (but very hard to follow with 60 forms!)..

Anyway you can make every child to subscribe to an event that it raise when you press save.